# SQL query on transaction

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a bank transaction table as below. I need to write an SQL query to calculate the remaining balance in each account after each transaction.

#### Bank_Transaction Table

| account_number | transaction_date | transaction_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12121 | 2020-05-21 | 100 |
| 12121 | 2020-05-22 | -50 |
| 12121 | 2020-05-23 | -20 |
| 23456 | 2020-05-21 | 200 |
| 23456 | 2020-05-23 | -200 |
| 13579 | 2020-05-25 | 100 |
| 24680 | 2020-05-20 | 150 |
| 24680 | 2020-05-25 | -100 |

We are also given a transaction table consisting of transaction_id, user_id, transaction_date, product_id and quantity. We need to query the number of users who purchased products on multiple days. (Note that a given user can purchase multiple products on a single day).

#### Transaction Table

| transaction_id | User_id | transaction_date | Product_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | U1 | 2020-12-16 | P1 | 263 |
| 2 | U2 | 2020-12-16 | P2 | 263 |
| 3 | U3 | 2020-12-16 | P3 | 294 |
| 4 | U4 | 2020-12-16 | P4 | 351 |
| 5 | U5 | 2020-12-17 | P5 | 351 |
| 6 | U6 | 2020-12-17 | P6 | 582 |
| 7 | U7 | 2020-12-18 | P7 | 456 |
| 8 | U8 | 2020-12-18 | P8 | 826 |
| 9 | U9 | 2020-12-18 | P9 | 826 |

How can I do this?

Comment: What query have you tried ?

Comment: You can use SUM() on the first one and COUNT() on the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like homework assignments.

First problem: join the table to itself so you can sum the transactions up to and including the current date:

```
select t.*, sum(h.amount) as balance from Transaction as t left join Transaction as h on h.account = t.account and h.date <= t.date group by t.*;
```

or something along those lines.

Second problem: group by user, count distinct days, filter using `having` clause.

Comment: when I am running your query it is throwing error. Failed to execute query, Error: Incorrect syntax near '*'.

Comment: i have tried different query 
select t.account_number, sum(h.amount) as balance from trans as t
inner join trans as h
on t.account_number = h.account_number and h.trans_date = t.trans_date
group bt t.account_number
this is giving me the final result after all the transcations group by account number but not after each transaction.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. If you group by account number then you get the end result per account number (sort of). If how ever you would group by individual transaction then you would get the result per transaction. And that was what I mean with "group by t.*". If that is bad syntax in mysql (I suppose it is) then you will have to list the indidivual fields of the transaction table, so "group by t.account_number, t.transaction_date, t.transaction_amount".

Comment: I got a solution for 2nd one but not able to get output for question 1.